# Can’t set custom font when using SASS - Ionic framework

Tags: css, sass, ionic-framework, font-face, compass-sass

I would like to set a custom font using SASS.
I was able to do that when I was using the default configuration with style.css file but when I try to run the same code on ionic.app.scss it doesn't work.

//style.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bariol_Regular';
src: url('../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.eot');
src: url('../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.svg#Bariol_Regular') format('svg');
}

.login_title {
font-family: "Bariol_Regular";
text-align: center;
}
```

//ionic.app.scss

```
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

//Common
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bariol_Regular';
    src: url("../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.eot");
    src: url("../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.eot") format('embedded-opentype'),
         url("../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.woff2") format('woff2'),
         url("../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.woff") format('woff'),
         url("../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.ttf") format('truetype'),
         url("../lib/ionic/fonts/Bariol_Regular.svg#Bariol_Regular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";

.login_title {
    font-family: "Bariol_Regular";
    text-align: center;
}
```

The scss get compiled correctly, but then the font of the login-title class doesn't display the right font, but just the ionic default font.

Comment: So what doesn't work about it?  Does it compile?  Is there an error?  Did you check the compiled CSS to verify that your changes are there and appear as they should be?

Comment: It compiles but it doesn't display the right font, I've checked the compiled CSS and it seems to be correct.

Comment: So did you check your inspector to see what styles are being applied to the element?  Did you verify that the path to the font is correct?

Comment: Yes, the style get applied to the element. May you tell me how can I verify that the path to the font is correct?

Comment: Can you download it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whats happening is your CSS is being called AFTER the Ionic styles, and they are getting priority over your change.

Place your .login_title, and all future style changes, ABOVE the Ionic @import

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem here is, not sure how you can provide an answer.  You do understand that the 2nd block of code is Sass, right?